# How to SparkSQL load csv with header on FROM statement

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark SQL FROM statement can be specified file path and format.
but, header ignored when load csv.
can use header for column name?

```
~ > cat test.csv
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

```scala
scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM csv.`test.csv`").show()
19/06/12 23:44:40 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database csv, returning NoSuchObjectException
+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

I want to.

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do it in plain SQL you should create a table or view first:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW foo
USING csv 
OPTIONS (
  path 'test.csv',
  header true
);
```

and then `SELECT` from it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

To use this method with `SparkSession.sql` remove trailing `;` and execute each statement separately.

Comment: nice idea!! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think a pure SQL solution is available in Spark 2.4.3 which is the latest version when writing this. This syntax is parsed using rule [`ResolveSQLOnFile`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/rules.scala#L37) which is always calling [`DataSource`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L88) constructor with [an empty options map](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/rules.scala#L45).

I can verify that putting a break-point to `DataSource` constructor and modifying `options` to `Map("header" -> "true")` does the trick so obviously this is where it should be implemented.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ollik1, may I know the interface you are using in your answer?

Comment: @Deepak by interface do you mean the GUI? It is IntelliJ IDEA with scala plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("test.csv")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

A SQL way is below:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("test.csv")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table").show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: @恵砂川 Of course we can use SQL, I have updated my answer with a SQL way.You also should load data first and then select.

Comment: sorry, I want to configure everything from SQL.   
I trying to do analysis any file by SQL interface, spark is relay for SQL and file.  
Is it possible?